# Is it OK to style the <html> tag?

Tags: coding-style, background, html

Sometimes you want two body backgrounds. One for the header and one for the footer.
I accidentally discovered that it is possible to style the actual `<html>` tag.

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

CSS:

```
html {background:#000}
```

Is it OK to style this, or will it cause any problem?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that some UI frameworks (most notably jQuery UI) do not support documents where the HTML or BODY tag has positioning or layout applied via CSS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although it's debatable as to whether it's valid [[see here]](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#background):

> For HTML documents, however, we recommend that authors specify the
>   background for the BODY element rather than the HTML element. ...

Many large sites still use it with seemingly consistent results.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Less tags counts and sometimes you want the background to be height to be heigher than the footer div...

Comment: Gotcha - I'll remove my question regarding they "why" of styling the HTML tag.

Comment: @Stano - I've updated my answer (I believe something was updated in the documentation since over a year ago when this was answered, as my link used to go to a spot that specifically showed it was "ok").  Thanks for the input/update/link!  If you still want to take back your up-vote, you likely can now, as the answer has been edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's OK to style the `html` tag.

Answer (score 3):

It is very common practice. Used all the time on many websites including this one.