# Should I apply styles directly to the <html> tag?

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it OK to style the <html> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590441/is-it-ok-to-style-the-html-tag)
>   [Is correct to set CSS property to html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089475/is-correct-to-set-css-property-to-html-tag)

Is it valid or ok to apply styles directly to the `<html>` tag?

Example:

```
<html class="myclass">
```

Example 2:

```
<html style="background-color: #000000;">
```

I think the answer is no, but I would like a solid confirmation from the community.

Comment: You don't really need a class. The `<html>` element can only appear once. Just use `html { background-color: #000000 }` in your style sheet.

Comment: For general styling purposes you probably won't need a class. However you *will* need a class or ID if you want to apply different styles to `html` on different pages of your site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's both valid and okay to apply styles to the `<html>` element. I often use it to apply full-page background gradients:

```css
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #eee, #ddd);
}
```

Or make an element take up the entire available height:

```css
html, body, #element {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

When applied to only the `<body>` element, this kind of thing doesn't work. And, of course, don't use inline styles.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this was more of a curiousity question so I wouldnt have gone the inline style route. I just put that up as an example just to be thorough.

Answer (score 0):

External stylesheets are the best way to handle styles; this allows you to apply the same styles throughout the whole website, making updating a piece of cake. Plus, it cuts down on the size of the HTML file, makes the load time that much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it usually isn't good practice. Having said that it really depends on your project. It's okay for trying things out quickly, but I would recommend using a class and putting the style into a seperate stylesheet once you're happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding classes to the `<body>` tag to style content by page is much more common.

Answer (score -1):

it is valid to apply styles directly to the html tag but it is very bad practice. you should always separate your css and html.